# DRF serialize PK Field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

-Solved-
This request was never going to work as some servers and browsers don't process body params from a GET request however Postman simply processes the request as expected and this was the reason why I got very confused and not sure what to look for. Instead use query params if you wish to filter data in a REST

-updated for more clarification-

1. I have 2 models CustomUser and Category, added User FK to Categories
2. updated my serializers to account for that ( not sure this part is correct tho )
3. on a Ajax GET request I pass the user id so I can grab only the categories that have the specified FK
4. in my Views request.get.data('user_id') brings back None
5. if I run the same request via Postman then I get the desired results

Any clues on why this would happen?

Apologies if my initial post was vague.

```
class CategorySerializer(TaggitSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=CustomUser.objects.all())
    posts = PostSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    tags = TagListSerializerField()
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'posts', 'tags', 'author')


# User Serializer
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id', 'email')
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get clear, do you have trouble reading the `id` in the response or writing it to the database?